# Multiple WEB API projects with multiple Stratup.cs files behaves like partial classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-signalr

I have .net core project solution with multiple WEB API projects and each has its own Stratup.cs file. all projects are referenced by a base WEB API Project that is hosted. My question is does what you put in different Startup.cs files gets merged to base Startup.cs file ?  I need to add signalR configuration to one project so I can add it to Startup.cs of that project rather than adding everything in the base project Startup.cs like  Partial classes behave.

Comment: This article from Andrew Lock might help :) https://andrewlock.net/exploring-istartupfilter-in-asp-net-core/ I don't think they will be automatically merged without using something like IStartupFilter.

Answer (score 0):

> multiple WEB API projects and each has its own Stratup.cs file.

Every web api project is it's own indpeendent .exe file and application.

> My question is does what you put in different Startup.cs files gets merged to base
>   Startup.cs file ?

They do not get merged. Not if they are independent web applicaiton projects as you say.

Merging then should or have to happen on the IIS level by marking them into separate folders that are applicaitons. THey are totally independent.

Now, if they are NOT totally independent, then you do not ahve mutliple Web Api projects. You could have areas there, in which case there is only ONE startup.cs which still indicates the startup - of the ONE project that actually is a web api project.

Comment: base WEB API project is having references to child WEB API projects, so what I put in child Startup files gets merged into base project Startup and builds one exe.

Comment: Yeah, but that does not make them one project. Why the heck do you even think that referenecing a compiled project will magically merge the source code?

Comment: I think u got it bit confused, I compile only the base API Project, I know source codes dont get merged, My question was since Stratup files are there in all API project if they get merged to one Stratup. like Partial classes behave.